# After Ajax request hover event doesn't load to image thumbail to display bigger image

Tags: datatables

I use datatables tot display a thumbnail in the first column. With jquery I display the original bigger picture when I hover the thumbnail.

Everything works fine until I decided to load the content into the table via Ajax. The hover event won't bind to the thumnail.

I tried all sorts of things. Read something about delagate, but can't get it to work. Can anyone help me?

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
 <td class="dtr-control"><a href="../images/cont/257.jpg" class="hover">
   <img src="../images/redcont_thumb/1757.jpg" class="mediabank-preview-thumbnail"></a>
 </td>
 <td>Description</td>
</tr>
```

Hover Jquery code:

```
$('a.hover').hover(function(e){ 
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('<img id="largeImage" src="' + href + '" alt="image" />')
  .css({'top':e.pageY + offsetY,'left':e.pageX + offsetX})
  .appendTo('body');
}, function(){
  $('#largeImage').remove();  // Delete displaying picture
});
$('a.hover').mousemove(function(e){
  $('#largeImage').css({'top':e.pageY + offsetY,'left':e.pageX + offsetX});
});
$('a.hover').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Hover won't work, so I uses 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave'. Everything works fine.

```
    // Hover images
    var offsetX = 20;
    var offsetY = -250  
    $('#table_mediaBank').on('mouseenter', 'a.hover', function (e) {        
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('<img id="largeImage" src="' + href + '" alt="image" />')
        .css({'top':e.pageY + offsetY,'left':e.pageX + offsetX})
        .appendTo('body');
    });
    $('#table_mediaBank').on('mouseleave', 'a.hover', function () {             // Verwijder het displayen van de afbeelding
        $('#largeImage').remove();
    });
    $('#table_mediaBank').on('mousemove', 'a.hover', function (e) {         verplaatsen
        $('#largeImage').css({'top':e.pageY + offsetY,'left':e.pageX + offsetX});
    });
    $('#table_mediaBank').on('click', 'a.hover', function (e) {         
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Delegate: Change your listeners to follow this convention: `$('table').on('hover', 'a.hover', function() { ...` -- and you can make the `table` any non-dynamic element container. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Hi Kinglish. I try this, but it doesn't work:   $('#table_mediaBank').on('hover', 'a.hover', function(e){

   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   $('<img id="largeImage" src="' + href + '" alt="image" />')
   .css({'top':e.pageY + offsetY,'left':e.pageX + offsetX})
   .appendTo('body');
  }